# How to pass data in Adapter to Activity from radio button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, viewstub

in my activity i have viewstub to call recycleview & other layout
in recycleview i need to insert skor from radiobutton to Main activity

like this

[image]

if i choose radiobutton skor inside main layout increase

this My bind i just use text cause i don't know to send skor

```
   package com.sariazhariyah.eassessmentinteraktif;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class sikapadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<sikapadapter.ViewHolder> {

    String option[];

    public sikapadapter(String[] option) {
        this.option = option;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycleview_sikap_layout,parent,false);
        sikapadapter.ViewHolder aadvh = new sikapadapter.ViewHolder(view);
        return aadvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.text.setText(option[position]);
        int Radioid = holder.radio.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return option.length;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView text;
        RadioGroup radio;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recytexttampil);
            radio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
        }
    }
}
```

this is main_activity where i use viewstub

```
    String s1[];
        s1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.option);

        ViewStub viewStub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub);
        //call layout where contain recycleview
        viewStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.penilaian_sikap_layout);
        View inflatedView = viewStub.inflate();

        recycle = (RecyclerView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.recyclesikap);
        recycle.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycle.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mAdapter = new sikapadapter(s1);
        recycle.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: you can achieve this using listener, if you really need help please post your entire adapter

Comment: i has been insert all of my adapter into question, i have RadioGroup if i checkradio button...it increase skor in my main activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create the interface inside your adapter:

```
  interface OnRadioChangeListener{
        void onRadioChange(RadioGroup radioGroup,int checkedId);
    }
```

Then declare the listener inside the adapter, that should be passed from the activity:

```
private OnRadioChangeListener onRadioChangeListener;
public sikapadapter(String[] option,OnRadioChangeListener onRadioChangeListener) {
    this.option = option;
    this.onRadioChangeListener = onRadioChangeListener;
}
```

and in onBindViewHolder() method inside your Adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.text.setText(option[position]);
    holder.radio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if(onRadioChangeListener!=null){
                onRadioChangeListener.onRadioChange(group,checkedId);
            }
        }
    });
    int Radioid = holder.radio.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
}
```

Now let's go to your mainActivity:

wherever you are creasting the adapter, just add the listener like this, for example:

```
skipadapter = new skipadapter (option,new skipadapter.OnRadioChangeListener(){
void onRadioChange(RadioGroup group,int checkedId){
//do whatever u wanna do here in your activity
}
});
```

by the way, `skipadapter` is not a naming convention that you should follow, change it to `SkipAdapter`

Comment: i still have error code, when use adapter, ```mAdapter = new sikapadapter(s1, ......)```  i don't know what data i can use to insert onRadionChangelistener

Comment: Error is gone, i use implement in my main activity